# /dev/sda equivalent in Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, disk-image

Is there an equivalent to `/dev/sda` in Windows, without using Cygwin or other external tools?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/974448/dev-fd0-equivalent-on-windows-writing-directly-to-tar-floppy?rq=1 seems related. Might help to give us a broader idea on why you need this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, `\\?\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0`. Win32 programs like [dd.exe](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) should understand this (see its documentation for a few more examples), although .NET-based ones might not.

The Windows equivalent of /dev, `\\?\`, can be browsed using [WinObj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/winobj.htm).

Most graphical disk-imaging programs just present a list of disks... use one of those.

Comment: Thanks! Is there also one to access the drive, not just one partition?

Comment: `Partition0` *is* the whole drive.

Comment: I'd say the Windows equivalent of `/dev` is `\Device`...